# Creating a Ones and Zeros matrix in R from features

Tags: r

I have a dataset like so:

```
  Name    |   Pet    | isTrain  | 
---------------------------------
 Ben      | Dog      |    1     | 
 Kim      | Cat      |    0     | 
 Kim      | Rabbit   |    0     |
```

How do I make this into a matrix in R where the Name is the row and the Pet is the column, and isTrain is the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(isTrain ~ Name + Pet, df1)
# Pet
#Name  Cat Dog Rabbit
#  Ben   0   1      0
#  Kim   0   0      0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c('Ben', 'Kim', 'Kim'),
     Pet = c('Dog', 'Cat', 'Rabbit'), isTrain = c(1, 0, 0))
```